# Erro Android Studio 1.5.1

Tags: android, android-studio, thread

Boa noite, sou novo com desenvolvimento Android e em meu primeiro projeto estou tendo erro o seguinte erro "Exception in thread "png-cruncher_20", logo abaixo segue o log completo do erro, alguém poderia me ajuda?

```
> `Executing tasks: [:app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources]

Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72301Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportDesign2301Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42301Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAuth830Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBase830Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBasement830Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesMeasurement830Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugGoogleServices
:app:generateDebugResources
:app:mergeDebugResources
Exception in thread "png-cruncher_20" java.lang.RuntimeException: Timed out while waiting for slave aapt process, make sure the aapt execute at C:\Android\sdk\build-tools\23.0.1\aapt.exe can run successfully (some anti-virus may block it) or try setting environment variable SLAVE_AAPT_TIMEOUT to a value bigger than 5 seconds
    at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.waitForReady(AaptProcess.java:108)
    at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.creation(QueuedCruncher.java:110)
    at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:203)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Exception in thread "png-cruncher_14" java.lang.RuntimeException: Timed out while waiting for slave aapt process, make sure the aapt execute at C:\Android\sdk\build-tools\23.0.1\aapt.exe can run successfully (some anti-virus may block it) or try setting environment variable SLAVE_AAPT_TIMEOUT to a value bigger than 5 seconds
    at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.waitForReady(AaptProcess.java:108)
    at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.creation(QueuedCruncher.java:110)
    at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:203)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Exception in thread "png-cruncher_16" java.lang.RuntimeException: Timed out while waiting for slave aapt process, make sure the aapt execute at C:\Android\sdk\build-tools\23.0.1\aapt.exe can run successfully (some anti-virus may block it) or try setting environment variable SLAVE_AAPT_TIMEOUT to a value bigger than 5 seconds
    at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.waitForReady(AaptProcess.java:108)
    at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.creation(QueuedCruncher.java:110)
    at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:203)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Exception in thread "png-cruncher_17" java.lang.RuntimeException: Timed out while waiting for slave aapt process, make sure the aapt execute at C:\Android\sdk\build-tools\23.0.1\aapt.exe can run successfully (some anti-virus may block it) or try setting environment variable SLAVE_AAPT_TIMEOUT to a value bigger than 5 seconds
    at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.waitForReady(AaptProcess.java:108)
    at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.creation(QueuedCruncher.java:110)
    at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:203)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Exception in thread "png-cruncher_12" java.lang.RuntimeException: Timed out while waiting for slave aapt process, make sure the aapt execute at C:\Android\sdk\build-tools\23.0.1\aapt.exe can run successfully (some anti-virus may block it) or try setting environment variable SLAVE_AAPT_TIMEOUT to a value bigger than 5 seconds
    at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.waitForReady(AaptProcess.java:108)
    at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.creation(QueuedCruncher.java:110)
    at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:203)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Exception in thread "png-cruncher_13" java.lang.RuntimeException: Timed out while waiting for slave aapt process, make sure the aapt execute at C:\Android\sdk\build-tools\23.0.1\aapt.exe can run successfully (some anti-virus may block it) or try setting environment variable SLAVE_AAPT_TIMEOUT to a value bigger than 5 seconds
    at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.waitForReady(AaptProcess.java:108)
    at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.creation(QueuedCruncher.java:110)
    at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:203)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Exception in thread "png-cruncher_19" java.lang.RuntimeException: Timed out while waiting for slave aapt process, make sure the aapt execute at C:\Android\sdk\build-tools\23.0.1\aapt.exe can run successfully (some anti-virus may block it) or try setting environment variable SLAVE_AAPT_TIMEOUT to a value bigger than 5 seconds
    at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.waitForReady(AaptProcess.java:108)
    at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.creation(QueuedCruncher.java:110)
    at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:203)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Exception in thread "png-cruncher_1" java.lang.RuntimeException: Timed out while waiting for slave aapt process, make sure the aapt execute at C:\Android\sdk\build-tools\23.0.1\aapt.exe can run successfully (some anti-virus may block it) or try setting environment variable SLAVE_AAPT_TIMEOUT to a value bigger than 5 seconds
    at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.waitForReady(AaptProcess.java:108)
    at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.creation(QueuedCruncher.java:110)
    at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:203)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Exception in thread "png-cruncher_18" java.lang.RuntimeException: Timed out while waiting for slave aapt process, make sure the aapt execute at C:\Android\sdk\build-tools\23.0.1\aapt.exe can run successfully (some anti-virus may block it) or try setting environment variable SLAVE_AAPT_TIMEOUT to a value bigger than 5 seconds
    at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.waitForReady(AaptProcess.java:108)
    at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.creation(QueuedCruncher.java:110)
    at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:203)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Exception in thread "png-cruncher_15" java.lang.RuntimeException: Timed out while waiting for slave aapt process, make sure the aapt execute at C:\Android\sdk\build-tools\23.0.1\aapt.exe can run successfully (some anti-virus may block it) or try setting environment variable SLAVE_AAPT_TIMEOUT to a value bigger than 5 seconds
    at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.waitForReady(AaptProcess.java:108)
    at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.creation(QueuedCruncher.java:110)
    at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:203)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Exception in thread "png-cruncher_9" java.lang.RuntimeException: Timed out while waiting for slave aapt process, make sure the aapt execute at C:\Android\sdk\build-tools\23.0.1\aapt.exe can run successfully (some anti-virus may block it) or try setting environment variable SLAVE_AAPT_TIMEOUT to a value bigger than 5 seconds
    at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.waitForReady(AaptProcess.java:108)
    at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.creation(QueuedCruncher.java:110)
    at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:203)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Exception in thread "png-cruncher_7" java.lang.RuntimeException: Timed out while waiting for slave aapt process, make sure the aapt execute at C:\Android\sdk\build-tools\23.0.1\aapt.exe can run successfully (some anti-virus may block it) or try setting environment variable SLAVE_AAPT_TIMEOUT to a value bigger than 5 seconds
    at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.waitForReady(AaptProcess.java:108)
    at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.creation(QueuedCruncher.java:110)
    at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:203)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Exception in thread "png-cruncher_6" java.lang.RuntimeException: Timed out while waiting for slave aapt process, make sure the aapt execute at C:\Android\sdk\build-tools\23.0.1\aapt.exe can run successfully (some anti-virus may block it) or try setting environment variable SLAVE_AAPT_TIMEOUT to a value bigger than 5 seconds
    at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.waitForReady(AaptProcess.java:108)
    at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.creation(QueuedCruncher.java:110)
    at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:203)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Exception in thread "png-cruncher_10" java.lang.RuntimeException: Timed out while waiting for slave aapt process, make sure the aapt execute at C:\Android\sdk\build-tools\23.0.1\aapt.exe can run successfully (some anti-virus may block it) or try setting environment variable SLAVE_AAPT_TIMEOUT to a value bigger than 5 seconds
    at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.waitForReady(AaptProcess.java:108)
    at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.creation(QueuedCruncher.java:110)
    at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:203)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Exception in thread "png-cruncher_8" java.lang.RuntimeException: Timed out while waiting for slave aapt process, make sure the aapt execute at C:\Android\sdk\build-tools\23.0.1\aapt.exe can run successfully (some anti-virus may block it) or try setting environment variable SLAVE_AAPT_TIMEOUT to a value bigger than 5 seconds
    at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.waitForReady(AaptProcess.java:108)
    at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.creation(QueuedCruncher.java:110)
    at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:203)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Exception in thread "png-cruncher_11" java.lang.RuntimeException: Timed out while waiting for slave aapt process, make sure the aapt execute at C:\Android\sdk\build-tools\23.0.1\aapt.exe can run successfully (some anti-virus may block it) or try setting environment variable SLAVE_AAPT_TIMEOUT to a value bigger than 5 seconds
    at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.waitForReady(AaptProcess.java:108)
    at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.creation(QueuedCruncher.java:110)
    at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:203)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Exception in thread "png-cruncher_5" java.lang.RuntimeException: Timed out while waiting for slave aapt process, make sure the aapt execute at C:\Android\sdk\build-tools\23.0.1\aapt.exe can run successfully (some anti-virus may block it) or try setting environment variable SLAVE_AAPT_TIMEOUT to a value bigger than 5 seconds
    at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.waitForReady(AaptProcess.java:108)
    at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.creation(QueuedCruncher.java:110)
    at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:203)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Exception in thread "png-cruncher_2" java.lang.RuntimeException: Timed out while waiting for slave aapt process, make sure the aapt execute at C:\Android\sdk\build-tools\23.0.1\aapt.exe can run successfully (some anti-virus may block it) or try setting environment variable SLAVE_AAPT_TIMEOUT to a value bigger than 5 seconds
    at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.waitForReady(AaptProcess.java:108)
    at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.creation(QueuedCruncher.java:110)
    at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:203)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Exception in thread "png-cruncher_3" java.lang.RuntimeException: Timed out while waiting for slave aapt process, make sure the aapt execute at C:\Android\sdk\build-tools\23.0.1\aapt.exe can run successfully (some anti-virus may block it) or try setting environment variable SLAVE_AAPT_TIMEOUT to a value bigger than 5 seconds
    at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.waitForReady(AaptProcess.java:108)
    at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.creation(QueuedCruncher.java:110)
    at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:203)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Exception in thread "png-cruncher_4" java.lang.RuntimeException: Timed out while waiting for slave aapt process, make sure the aapt execute at C:\Android\sdk\build-tools\23.0.1\aapt.exe can run successfully (some anti-virus may block it) or try setting environment variable SLAVE_AAPT_TIMEOUT to a value bigger than 5 seconds
    at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.waitForReady(AaptProcess.java:108)
    at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.creation(QueuedCruncher.java:110)
    at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:203)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
`
```

Comment: Verifique se todas as bibliotecas estão instaladas! principalmente o Bulid Tools! CLique em SDK Manager, para atualizar!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tente baixar o *Android Support Tools*:

- Abra o SDK manager;
- clique na aba "SDK Tools";
- marque o item "Android Support Library";
- Clique em "Apply".